# Find Source of Massive Page Hits/Reloads

Tags: azure, http, request, azure-web-app-service

I have a protected site with about 250 daily active users. There's an issue where these users are reloading the same page over and over again. Once a minute or more. They're not doing manually - it happens the entire day and night.

The same page loads, they're logged out (due to cookie expiring) and then the page is requested, which redirects to a login page - and this happens thousands of times. I have times where I have 20 requests/second for hours.

I can't duplicate it. I can't isolate it. I have no idea why and where the cause is. I've checked code for reload, refreshes, etc. I have left my browser open.

Is it a browser extension, email, broken js, - I have no idea.

I have poured over AI logs, code, console messages, I'm going crazy here

Any suggestions on finding the source?

Azure App Services on Linux
ASP.NET Core 3.1
Application Insights

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what is the issue. Is the 'reload' part after cookie expiring?

Comment: I don't have a reload. That's not part of my code. Pages just continue to refresh as often as twice a minute. Once the cookie expires, then it's double the load - once the page is loaded and then redirected to login. You would think once it's redirected to login we'd be done. But, that other page tries again and redirects again. And the cycle continues to count of 200K views in 24 hours (for only 250 users). I need to find out what's causing this.

Comment: are you using Single Page Application? Or it's just pure MVC + aspnet core?

Comment: asp.net core 3.1 mvc/razor. No SPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. VisualPing - a chrome extension.

I was finally able to get into a user and go into their computer - and it was an extension that was checking for an updated element on a page. Checking every minute. Every user - some multiple checks per minute. Each browser would do the same checks.

wow.